# A duplicate question. where the duplicate could have more answers

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, duplicate-questions

[How to generate barcode in vb.net without using 3rd party tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142539/how-to-generate-barcode-in-vb-net-without-using-3rd-party-tool/17142613#17142613)

This question is a possible duplicate

[Code 128 Barcode generation in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844687/code-128-barcode-generation-in-vb-net)

However, after investigating the answers to the other question, not sure if there has been enough attention to it, in terms of solutions. I believe more answers could be provided.

So do I answer the older question and offer a link as a duplicate with answers and flag the newer question, or answer the newer question?

What's the best thing to do in these situations?

Please be mindful that I am using this situation as an example. You do not have to agree whether the answers are sufficient or not, that will turn this question into a separate debate. This question can be applied generically.

Comment: Not sure about your specific example, but the general rule is: vote (or flag) to close as duplicate the question with the inferior answers, and use the question with the best answers as the original.

Comment: the new answer has only just been posted. The answers are not bad on the original question, just could be more options there

Comment: Then I would answer the "better" question and flag/vote the other one as dupe

Comment: Yes I am thinking I will do that ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate-closing need not be chronological. Try to always close dupes such that the duplicate target is the *better* question (with better answers).

Alternatively, you can flag for a merge, which will move all answers to the better question.

Comment: oh, I didn't know I would flag for a merge ty